# rake db:migrate giving error for mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

while running rake db:migrate i get the following error :

> rake db:migrate
>
> (in /Users/hrastogi/ruby_project/contactlist)
> rake aborted!
> no such file to load -- mysql2/mysql2

the trace shows that

> /Users/hrastogi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require'
>
> /Users/hrastogi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

So i went to mysql2.rb and i see the error is at line

```
require 'mysql2/mysql2
```

this means that mysql2 is missing some modules.

The way i installed mysql2 is

> sudo gem install mysql2 --version="0.2.6" --  --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include

and my gem list shows

> abstract (1.0.0)
> actionmailer (3.0.9)
> actionpack (3.0.9)
> activemodel (3.0.9)
> activerecord (3.0.9)
> activeresource (3.0.9)
> activesupport (3.0.9)
> arel (2.0.10)
> builder (2.1.2)
> bundler (1.0.15)
> erubis (2.6.6)
> i18n (0.5.0)
> mail (2.2.19)
> mime-types (1.16)
> mysql2 (0.2.6)
> polyglot (0.3.1)
> rack (1.2.3)
> rack-mount (0.6.14)
> rack-test (0.5.7)
> rails (3.0.9)
> railties (3.0.9)
> rake (0.8.7)
> rdoc (3.8)
> redcar (0.11)
> rubyzip (0.9.4)
> sqlite3 (1.3.3)
> thor (0.14.6)
> treetop (1.4.9)
> tzinfo (0.3.29)

i saw similar posts here but didnt get much help...
mysql version is 5.1.57 for 64bit amd mac os is 10.6.6

i tried installing with giving path name to mysql_config but that didnt work.
any help appreciated.

[image: error while updating mysql2 gem]

Di i need to have libmysqlclient.16.dylib or any other library for client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gem called 'mysql2'. the convention **require 'mysql2/mysql2** is about subdirectories to organize the files autoload.

use this in your Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2',              '~> 0.2.7'
```

Comment: i already have as gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6' . I added '~>' too but it doesnt work. After having in Gemfile do i need to do some other task before running rake ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the mysql2 gem? You are using an old version, the newest version is 0.3.6.

In your Gemfile make sure you don't specify the version:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

And then you have to run:

```
bundle update
```

If you are using RVM to install a gem you are supposed to do only:

```
gem install mysql2
```

In case you want to do it with options and sudo you have to do:

```
rvmsudo gem install -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

If you don't have RVM, I recommend you start using it.

---

Other problem I used to have with mysql2 was when I didn't have the mysql-devel (in CentOS). Maybe you are missing the developer library of MySQL.

Comment: i downgraded to 0.2.6 because i read somewhere that 0.3.6 is for rails 3.1x and above.. also while doing bundle update i get error for mysql2 gem.. the logs i will post ..

Comment: The gem works for both rails 3.0x and 3.1x. I am using it in a project of each with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened several times to me and this is usually my order of ops:

`gem install mysql`

`gem install mysql2`

Then in my gem file:

```
gem 'mysql2',              '~> 0.2.7'
```

Then I run `bundle install`.  That's done the trick for me. :)