# Ruby Gem LoadError mysql2/mysql2 required

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Im trying to setup my rails server on OSX 10.8 but I can't get my rails server to run.

- Currently Im using a Zend Server with mysql 5.1.

- I also have istalled `brew` and `brew mysql`.

- And I used: 
 `gem install mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-opt-include=/usr/local/mysql/include`

**the server worked already but now, I always get this loadError below.**

This is what my Gemfile says:

```
ralphs-macbook-pro:admin-mockup zero$ bundle install
Using rake (10.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.7) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.7) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.7) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.7) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.7) 
Using activeresource (3.2.7) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.7) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.5) 
Using debugger-linecache (1.1.2) 
Using debugger (1.2.2) 
Using formtastic (2.2.1) 
Using haml (3.1.7) 
Using haml-rails (0.3.5) 
Using hirb (0.7.0) 
Using hpricot (0.8.6) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using kgio (2.7.4) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using php_serialize (1.2) 
Using polyamorous (0.5.0) 
Using rabl (0.7.8) 
Using railroady (1.1.0) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using rails (3.2.7) 
Using raindrops (0.10.0) 
Using randumb (0.3.0) 
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using squeel (1.0.13) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Using unicorn (4.4.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled
gem is installed.
```

And after starting `rails s`

```
/Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/zero/GitHub/admin-mockup/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/zero/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for this solutions:

- http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=50501
- [rake db:migrate giving error for mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737535/rake-dbmigrate-giving-error-for-mysql2)

Comment: ok, I changed my Gemfile to `gem 'mysql', '~> 0.3.11' ` but now I get: "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (Mysql2::Error)"

Comment: after that I development:
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 1):

after that I changed my database.yml as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  socket: /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
  #host: 127.0.0.1
```

so that I used my local zend MySQL socket.
In my case the ""Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (Mysql2::Error)" was gone.

Thx @dinnouti for the usefull links above.